# I received error 401 : unauthorized when accessing my web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I'm trying to run one of my web app APIs but when prompted for user and password, it responded with 401 access denied. I've tried changing from NTLM to Kerberos. It still won't work. I'm new to SharePoint.

This is how I call my API :

```js
var json = $.ajax({
        url: (serviceType == "wcf" ? wcfServicesUrl : servicesApi) + wcfServiceUri,
        type: type,
        data: data,        
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
)};
```

Comment: Can you share the code, where you are calling the API? You may need to add an auth header if you're calling it from JS

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the authentication settings in IIS for your Web API application.

[image: IIS Screenshot]

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may need one or more of these options enabled.

Your app pool identity also plays a role.  Make sure they user is properly authorized to access your content / data / etc.

Update: set Windows Authentication as Enabled, make sure all others are disabled. Do not use Kerberos. Add URL for your web app to Trusted Sites in your browser.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, I'm using ASP.NET WebAPI. We're using Windows Authentication, and i've change the authentication through IIS. It prompts me thrice @GlennFerrie

Comment: If you're testing from the server, your browser might not pass your identity to the web server automatically unless you mark it as a trusted site.

Comment: It still won't let me get through. I mark as both trusted sit and local intranet still got the authentication error. I'm using the remote desktop which is connected to the server.

Comment: And anonymous access is off? What's in your web.config?

Comment: yes. my anonymous access is all offed. which web.config ? my app pool ?

Comment: Web.config from the Web API

Comment: Reviewed your web.config. you need to configure `system.web/authorization` correctly. It's only present within your 'location' elements

Answer (score 0):

i have recently came across production issue where my PRODUCTION API server suddenly starts giving 401 unauthorized error , I searched a lot on internet but fruitless than I took support from Microsoft as this application was running fine , suddenly the error occurred , Microsoft just took a look on which dot net frame work the application is using mine was 4.0 , so they advised to go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

when an application is hosted on IIS , it compiles its dlls and other files once in this particular folder ,if it gets lock or corrupt the application will start giving 401 unauthorized error 
and delete the temp files and restarted IIS and Voala it start working .
Please mark it as a answer if you are comfortable

Answer (score 0):

401 can also be NTFS permissions, take a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david.wang/2005/07/15/howto-diagnose-401-x-http-errors-on-iis/):

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution, it worked in my case. First open IIS and click your site. And then:

1. Right click "Authentication"
2. Click "Open Feature"
3. Select "Anonymous Authentication"
4. Select "Edit" From "Actions" on the right
5. Select "Application Pool Identity"
6. Click "Ok"